# How to create an angled button with CSS and HTML5 without images

Tags: html, css, button

I have some problem with CSS. I want to create an angled button using CSS and HTML5, without images.

How to create it without images? I want the HTML5 output to be like this:

[image: button1]

I have tried this button:

```
border: solid 10px;
/* the border will curve into a 'D' */
border-radius: 10px 40px 40px 10px;
```

I also need to create this

[image: button2]

Any help is appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
button.testBtn {
  height:50px;
  width:150px;
    background: blue;
    position: relative;
    border:none;
    text-align:left;
}
button.testBtn span{
font-weight:bold;
font-size:18px;
margin-left:10px;
}

button.testBtn:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; right: 0;
    border-bottom: 50px solid white;
    border-left: 60px solid blue;
    width: 0;
}

/* ***************************************** */

button.myBtn {
  height:50px;
  width:150px;
    background: blue;
    position: relative;
    border:none;
    text-align:right;
}
button.myBtn span{
font-weight:bold;
font-size:18px;
}

button.myBtn:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid white;
    border-right: 60px solid blue;
    width: 0;
}
```

```html
<button class="testBtn">
<span>Button</span>
</button>

<br /><br /><br /><br />

<button class="myBtn">
<span>Button</span>
</button>
```

In Order to get shape as described in later comment. Please check btn with class **myBtn**

Comment: thans for help I really appreciate it.. its also work

Comment: but how to flipped this button https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNHBg.png output like this

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```css
.class{
background:#0077dd;
color:#fff;
padding:10px 20px;
    position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  height:20px;
  
  }

a.class:after {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top:40px solid #0077dd;
    border-right: 40px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -40px;
    content:"";
}
```

```html
<a class="class">Button</a>
```

Comment: thans for help I really appreciate it, its also work fine

Comment: @Eko Rudiyanto jay If you are happy with my answer then please give me +1 & accept my answer by press on checkmark under the arrow